# Bidual of subspaces of $L_1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a subspace of $L_1[0,1]$ which is also isomorphic to $L_1[0,1]$. Is it true that $M^{**}$ is complemented in $(L_1[0,1])^{**}$?

Comment: Did you read Bourgain's paper (at least the first page of it)? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140557/quotients-of-linfty

Comment: I echo @NarutakaOZAWA's comment. See also Bill Johnson's remarks about localization in his comments to the answer of your previous question

Comment: If you are happy with @M.G.'s answer then you should click the tick mark to "accept it".

Answer (score 4):

The asnwer is no. First, $M$ is not necessarily complemented in $L_1[0,1]$ (Bourgain). In fact, $M$ is complemented in $L_1[0,1]$ iff $L_1/M$ is a $\mathcal{L}_1$-space (Lindenstrauss lifting argument). Second, $L_1/M$ is a $\mathcal{L}_1$-space iff so is its bidual $L_1[0,1]^{**}/M^{\perp\perp}$.  Since Lindenstrauss argument applies also to $L_1[0,1]^{**}$, we conclude that $M^{\perp\perp}\equiv M^{**}$ is complemented in $L_1[0,1]^{**}$ iff $M$ is complemented in $L_1[0,1]$.